# Mutating an array with the elements of another array while maintaining order and existing instances

Tags: javascript, arrays, masking, mutation

Need help with an algorithm that takes two arrays and results in a specific comparison between them that maintains the same order:

- If _ID in existing but _ID not in overwriter, then do Not include element in result
- If _ID is in overwriter but _ID not in existing, then add element to RESULT
- If _ID is in both existing and overwriter, then add element with version/instance of _ID from existing to result

captial letter represents reference _ID
v# represents version/instance of reference _ID

1.

existing: [ Av1 Bv1 Cv1 Ev1 Fv1 Gv1 ]

overwriter: [ Bv2 Dv1 Fv2 Hv1 Jv1 ]

result: [ Bv1 Dv1 Fv1 Hv1 Jv1 ]

2.

existing: [ Bv1 Cv1 Ev1 Fv1 Gv1 ]

overwriter: [ Av1 Bv2 Dv1 Fv2 Hv1 Jv1 ]

result: [ Av1 Bv1 Dv1 Fv1 Hv1 Jv1 ]

3.

existing: [ Av1 Bv1 Cv1 Ev1 Fv1 Gv1 ]

overwriter: [ Av2 Bv2 Dv1 Fv2 Hv1 Jv1 ]

result: [ Av1 Bv1 Dv1 Fv1 Hv1 Jv1 ]

4.

existing: [ Cv1 Dv1 Ev1 ]

overwriter: [ Av1 Bv1 Dv2 Fv1 Hv1 Jv1 ]

result: [ Av1 Bv1 Dv1 Fv1 Hv1 Jv1 ]

5.

existing: [ Av1 Bv1 Cv1 Ev1 Fv1 Gv1 ]

overwriter: [ Dv1 ]

result: [ Dv1 ]

I am looking for a log(n) function that performs this mutation operation in one pass (perhaps with pivot indices for both existing and overwriter but I'm unsure).

do not want to use indexOf.

This is my log(n^2) solution using a shrinking tail technique:

```
let eIndx = 0,
    existing = [ Av1, Bv1, Cv1, Ev1, Fv1, Gv1 ],
    overwriter = [ Bv2, Dv1, Fv2, Hv1, Jv1 ];

overwriter.map( element => {

    while( element._ID !== existing[ eIndx ]._ID && 
           eIndx       !== existing.length ) {

        delete existing[ eIndx ];

        ++eIndx;
    }

    return eIndx !== existing.length ? existing[ eIndx ] : element;
});
```

This solution is slowest if none of the _ID's in existing are in overwriter.

I am not sure if I should be iterating through the existing array or the overwriter array.

In my expanded (more convoluted) solution that I've paraphrased this post from, I iterated through the overwriter and I had a hash dictionary to reference whether a _ID/version combo already existed in the future (later indeces that have yet to be iterated upon) of the array. I can no longer use that global dictionary and I am trying to figure out whether I need to make a local dictionary for each array instance or if there is a way i don't need the dictionary and just use the pivots to compare. A problem I see with the pivots in a log(n) solution is that it doesn't know whether the first element of overwriter is a new _ID without iterating through all of the existing array.

Mostly I am looking for something as fast as possible

I am most grateful for help you can share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and check the existence of the id.

```js
function merge(existing, overwriter) {
    const getId = s => s.split('v')[0]; // or whatever is suitable

    var versions = new Map;

    existing.forEach(s => versions.set(getId(s),  s));
    return overwriter.map(s => versions.get(getId(s)) || s);
}

console.log(merge([ 'Av1', 'Bv1','Cv1','Ev1','Fv1', 'Gv1' ],[ 'Bv2', 'Dv1','Fv2','Hv1','Jv1']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That sounds a bit like the code the OP is trying to replace.  But I think it's actually the only really useful approach.

Comment: thanks Scott and Nina. Would it be more advantageous to build that hash index of the existing array in the merge function at the moment the overwrite array arrives? or better to build the hash index when the existing array is originally created and just storing it (along with the existing array) until the overwrite array arrives?

Comment: I think that's going to be based on your application.  Obviously, rebuilding has a cost in time.  Storing it has a cost in space (and in complexity.)  I would try rebuilding and profile if necessary to see if it meets your needs.  That would definitely be simpler to maintain.  Only move to storing it it it causes performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this answer as a basis of discussion, even though, [based on previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853687/#comment84716012_48853687), I know it doesn't quite meet your needs.

It's recursive, which in Javascript, might well still mean that it's slow or could overflow the stack.  It is ready for tail call optimization, though, so eventually it shouldn't be too slow.  But being recursive, the code is quite clean.  *However*, it's based on an assumption I made from your examples that the lists were sorted.

```js
const original = [{"_ID": 2, "val": "a0"}, {"_ID": 3, "val": "a1"}, {"_ID": 5, "val": "a2"}, {"_ID": 7, "val": "a3"}, {"_ID": 11, "val": "a4"}, {"_ID": 13, "val": "a5"}, {"_ID": 17, "val": "a6"}, {"_ID": 19, "val": "a7"}]

const overwriter = [{"_ID": 1, "val": "b0"}, {"_ID": 2, "val": "b1"}, {"_ID": 3, "val": "b2"}, {"_ID": 5, "val": "b3"}, {"_ID": 8, "val": "b4"}, {"_ID": 13, "val": "b5"}, {"_ID": 21, "val": "b6"}, {"_ID": 34, "val": "b7"}]

const mergeLists = (a, b, combined = []) => a.length == 0
    ? combined.concat(b)
    : b.length == 0 
        ? combined
        : a[0]._ID < b[0]._ID 
            ? mergeLists(a.slice(1), b, combined)
            : a[0]._ID == b[0]._ID
                ? mergeLists(a.slice(1), b.slice(1), combined.concat([a[0]]))
                : mergeLists(a, b.slice(1), combined.concat([b[0]]))
         

console.log(mergeLists(original, overwriter))
```

Now given that we've found out that they aren't sorted, I think there is nothing better than recreating that index locally.  It will certainly be faster than searching the list every time (which would be `O(m * n)`.)

Property lookups, using an object for your index, are just barely slower than `O(1)`, so, at the cost of additional space, you still should be able to do this in `O(m + n)`.

That code should be pretty simple: create an index by reducing your existing data into an object, keyed on the `_ID` property, then iterate the overwriters, placing in your output either the matching one from the index, if it exists, or the overwritten one otherwise.

This still isn't mutating.  You could achieve that with an appropriate `splice`, but if you're doing so, make sure you iterate in reverse.  But I would recommend not mutating in any case.

In any case, this code would work with the data I used above.  If your IDs are anything other than Strings or Numbers, you should use Nina's `Map` version instead:

```
const mergeLists = (original, overwriter) => {
  const index = original.reduce((idx, val) => (idx[val._ID] = val, idx), {})
  return overwriter.map(val => index[val._ID] || val)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You speak of *log(n)* and *log(n<sup>2</sup>)* but obviously mean *O(n)* and *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* respectively.

You can achieve *O(n)* time complexity if you first create a map for the existing values, keyed by their id values. Then the loop over the overwriting array can fetch corresponding elements in constant time per fetch.

Here is an example:

```js
const existing = [
        { _id: "A", version: 1 }, 
        { _id: "B", version: 1 },
        { _id: "C", version: 1 },
        { _id: "E", version: 1 }, 
        { _id: "F", version: 1 },
        { _id: "G", version: 1 },
    ],
    overwriter = [
        { _id: "B", version: 2 },
        { _id: "D", version: 1 },
        { _id: "F", version: 2 },
        { _id: "H", version: 1 },
        { _id: "J", version: 1 },
    ];

const map = new Map(existing.map( o => [o._id, o] ));
const result = overwriter.map( el => map.get(el._id) || el );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```